# Can't seem to catch any HTML5 video events

Tags: html, events, video

I'm trying to change the 'display' CSS property of a div when the video I have on my page finishes playing. I've tried different methods: adding an eventhandler, and listening for the end event in a separate `<script>` tag (under the window.onload block). I'm trying a third option but can't get it to work either:

in the body:

```
<div id="feels_feel_container">
    <div id="AnswersWrapper" style="display: none">
        Some stuff here.
    </div>
    <div id="VideoWrapper">
        <video id="VideoWindow" src="../html/media/homepage.mp4" autoplay onended="VideoEnded()"/>  
    </div>
</div>
```

in the head:

```
<script>
    function VideoEnded() {
        AnswersWrapper.css("display", "block");
    }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I was calling an invalid argument in my VideoEnded() function.
I should've put $("#AnswersWrapper) instead of AnswersWrapper.

Please ignore :)